# Data Structure Help - Understanding the thought process

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, data-structures

```
public class Example {

    private static class Courses {
        public final String name;
        public final Courses[] children;

        public Courses(String name, Courses ... children) {
            this.name = name;
            this.children = children;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Courses courses =
                new Courses("School",
                        new Courses("Mathematics",
                                new Courses("Algebra"),
                                new Courses("Trig"),
                                new Courses("Calculus"),
                                new Courses("Calculus 2"),
                                new Courses("Geometry")),
                        new Courses("Sciences",
                                new Courses("Biology"),
                                new Courses("Chemistry"),
                                new Courses("Physics"),
                        new Courses("Business",
                                new Courses("Finances",
                                        new Courses("Accounting"),
                                        new Courses("Accounting 1"),
                                        new Courses("Accounting 2"),
                                new Courses("Administration",
                                        new Courses("Economics"),
                                        new Courses("Business Studies"),
                                        new Courses("Administration 1"),
                                        new Courses("Accounting"))),
                        new Courses("Physical Education"))));


                    System.out.println(find(courses, "Economics", courses.name));

        public static String find(Courses courses, String name, String currentPath) {

        if((courses.name).equals(name)){

            System.out.println(currentPath);

            return currentPath + " / " + name;

        }
        else{
            //System.out.println(currentPath);
            for(Courses child:courses.children){

                currentPath += " / " + child.name;

                find(child, name, currentPath);
            }

        }

        return currentPath + " / " + name;

    }
}
```

So this is the code that I have acquired. I'm trying to determine what the right thinking pattern should be when coding this find courses method. This is an array but I'm thinking of it in like a tree like manner and trying to find the answer. IS that something you guys would do too? I'm trying to find a path like this School / Business / Administration / Economics. But either I'm getting the whole path or it's iterating through the whole thing. Also, what's the approach you guys will take to accomplish this. I wrote a recursive method to achieve this, but its not working out.

Thanks, for your help

CC

Comment: Your question isn't really very clear. Is the problem the data structure, or the implementation of the recursive method?

Comment: Well, the data structure, as in the thinking behind solving a problem like this. And then obviously, I'm running into an issue with the method using recursion so, id that a way you would go or would you use something else to show the path?

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about it as a tree is obviously the way to go, as it is indeed a tree.

It might help you to think what you expect the method to do if the current value of `courses` was the parent of the node you want. That is in your case, if it's the Administration node. In your current implementation, you will iterate over all the children, never realizing you found the correct child!

As another hint, you would generally in recursion want to do something with the result of the recursive call. In your code, you call find(child, name, currentPath) and then you do nothing with the result!

Hope these hints help you.

Comment: Well I am putting in Economics for example in the call to the find Method and then I'm trying to return the currentPath with the name. However it's always going out of the loop and displaying School / Mathematics / Science / Business / Physical Edication / Economics. And that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

**Course.java**

```
public class Course {
    private Course parentCourse;
    private String name;

    public Course(String name){
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Course getParentCourse() {
        return parentCourse;
    }

    public void setParentCourse(Course parentCourse) {
        this.parentCourse = parentCourse;
    }
}
```

**Courses.java**

```
public class Courses {
    private List<Course> courses;

    public Courses(){

    }

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
        this.courses = courses;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
    Courses courses = new Courses();
    List listCourses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    Course generalMaths = new Course("General Maths");
    Course linAlgebra = new Course("Linear Algebra");
    linAlgebra.setParentCourse(generalMaths);

    listCourses.add(generalMaths);
    listCourses.add(linAlgebra);

    courses.setCourses(listCourses);
```

**Find path**

```
    for(Course course : courses.getCourses()){
        StringBuffer coursePath = new StringBuffer();
        coursePath.append(course.getName());
        while(course.getParentCourse() != null){
            course = course.getParentCourse();
            coursePath.append(" | "+course.getName());
        }
        System.out.println(coursePath);
    }
```

Comment: Oh gotcha! Thanks! But to focus on the code that I put, the thinking of it. Like as a tree and then using a recursive method to find the path, is that a good approach? How would you go about finding the path if you had to edit the find method?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the path finding. It requires some work on the order because right now it is reversed

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains some opinion-based (sub)questions. These we cannot answer, but we can help with your recursive algorithm.

The `if` branch of your `find` method seems alright. It enters that branch when an exact match occurs. The problem is in your `else` branch, where you need recursion to keep looking in the children courses.

Note that your method declaration returns a String.

```
public static String find(Courses, String, String)
```

And note that, when you recursively call this function, you are ignoring its return value, rendering the recursive call useless.

```
for (Courses child: courses.children) {
    currentPath += " / " + child.name;
    find(child, name, currentPath); // <-- this return value is being ignored!
}
```

Start by assigning the return value of the recursive search to some variable, and define a return value for when the search doesn't find the provided name (you will not find *Biology* under *Administration*, for instance). I'll assume that an empty String means the search didn't find the course.

```
String result = find(child, name, currentPath);
if (!result.isEmpty()) {
    // it has been found
}
```

Finally, note that you are changing the value of the `currentPath` variable on **each** iteration, by appending to it. That will result in erroneous paths, if the name is found after the first iteration. Assign that temporary path, for that iteration, to another variable.

Comment: So, should I just make nextPath = currentPath and return nextPath?

Comment: @CalmestChaos Start by assigning `currentPath` to a `nextPath`, and then append the child's name to the next path instead, so you always preserve the original path, in case your recursive call does not find the course. You're changing the original `currentPath`, and that's why you're getting those weird results, with all child courses.

Comment: So, I did do that, and when I do a System.out for the nextPath in the loop it does show that path in one of the iterations, however, the final return is School / Physical Education / Economics

Comment: @CalmestChaos In that case, either you're missing a return statement, or something is wrong with your variable assignments. I'm afraid we can't help without seeing your current code. If you do post your new code, do so by editing your question, or by posting a new question with your new problem.